# Prestashop theme HTML code customization

Tags: html, css, templates, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to ask if by buing a Prestashop theme it let me to add or modiffy its HTML source code?

I would like to substitute the "add to card" [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEBBf.png)button and replace it with a URL to redirect the customer to another website. Would it be possible? So the customer isn't actually purchasing anithing at my site and its only redirecting customers to other sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify any html that you want and can put any link anywhere you want if it doesn't contradict theme usage rules. But be aware that prestashop uses smarty templates engine and all html is inside smarty files, so it's better to be acquainted with the latter.